# How to do If-or operation in lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I get all book's information to one list and filter them with a keyword.

```
List<Book> books = bookService.getAllBooks();

List<Book> filteredBooks = books.stream().filter(b-> b.getName().contains(keyword) || b.getDescription().contains(keyword))
```

But, `b.getDescription()` can return null, so I got null pointer exception.

How can I do an operation in filter like `b.getName() OR IF !b.getDescription().isEmpty b.getDescription()`?

Comment: try `b.getDescription() != null && b.getDescription().contains(keyword)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
List<Book> filteredBooks = books.stream()
                                .filter(b-> b.getName().contains(keyword) ||
                                            (b.getDescription() != null && b.getDescription().contains(keyword)));
```

Comment: @YCF_L: More or less the same, IMHO :)

Comment: I did I guess, thabk